# How to put arrays from Roo excel sheet in two dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, excel, roo-gem

I am using the roo-gem in ruby to get excel sheet cell values.

I have a file 'ruby.rb' with:

```
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'roo'

xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('test_work.xls')
xls.each do |row|
  p row
end
```

my output in the terminal when I run ruby 'ruby.rb' is:

```
["id", "header2", "header3", "header4"]
["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]
["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]
```

when I add:

```
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'roo'

xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('test_work.xls')
xls.each do |row|
  two_dimensional = []
  two_dimensional << row
  p two_dimensional
end
```

I get:

```
[["id", "header2", "header3", "header4"]]
[["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]]
[["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]]
```

What I want is:

```
[["id", "header2", "header3", "header4"],
["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"],
["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]]
```

How would I go about doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: you realize that `xls` already has this structure before the loop right? if `xls.each { |row| p row }` comes out as you have described then `xls` is already the multidimensional array that you want. if you really wanted to add this unneeded complexity then `xls.map { |row| row}` will do this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare the array outside the `each` block. You're resetting it to `[]` every time the block is run. In that case, you will only append to **one** array.

```
two_dimensional = []
xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('test_work.xls')
xls.each do |row|
  two_dimensional << row
  p two_dimensional
end
```

Comment: Thanks Amit! Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: @Mike glad to have helped :)

Comment: Just to clarify you are taking a multidimensional `Array` and making a new one that looks exactly the same? Why would you need to do this? If your code works the way he wanted then `xls` is already what he wanted from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'

class InputExcelReader
$INPUTPATH = 'C:\test_input_excel.xlsx'
excel_data_array = Array.new()

workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open($INPUTPATH)
worksheets = workbook.sheets
puts worksheets
puts "Found #{worksheets.count} worksheets"

worksheets.each do |worksheet|
    puts "Reading: #{worksheet}"
    num_rows = 0
    workbook.sheet(worksheet).each_row_streaming do |row|
        if(num_rows>0)
            puts "Reading the row no: #{num_rows}"
            row_cells = row.map { |cell| 
                puts "Reading cells"
                cell.value              
            }
            excel_data_array.push(row_cells)            
        end
        num_rows += 1
    end
    puts excel_data_array.to_s
end
end
```